# Radio button select reflects in second group radio button in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I need a four radio button. First iteration generates 2 radio button & second iteration generates 2 radio button. If i select one of the Radio button in first section , then one of the radio button  in second selection is also selected. I want  two section containing 2 radio button each which dont reflect the changes on each other. Any help pls

```
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
    <div data-ng-repeat="choic in choice"  >
    <form >
  <input ng-model="parent.mustShow"  class="label_align" type="radio"          name="customer" value="no"  ><div class="mediumSubhead"> Information housed         </div><br/>
   <input ng-model="parent.mustShow"  class="label_align" type="radio"   name="customer" value="yes" >
 <div class="mediumSubhead"> Information housed   outside </div></form>
</div> 
 </div>
Controller.js
 var app = angular.module('EquityCompensation', []);
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.choice = [{id: 'choic1'},{id: 'choic2'}];
 });
```

Comment: Really don't understand what exactly you want..could you update your question

Comment: Sorry man, please open paint/gimp and try to draw what you want, and give me image link. ok?

Comment: I ellaborated my issue. pls take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to put the `mustShow` variable inside the choice array. So that would help you make the track of the each element. That will make your ng-model declaration to `ng-model="choic.mustShow"`

And to show the outer input element you could use filter over there that will check that any of the choice has `mustShow` option is ticked then you show the input element.

**Markup**

```
<div data-ng-repeat="choic in choice">
  <form>
    <input ng-model="choic.mustShow" class="label_align" type="radio" name="customer" value="no">
    <div class="mediumSubhead"> Information housed </div>
    <br/>
    <input ng-model="choic.mustShow" class="label_align" type="radio" name="customer" value="yes">
    <div class="mediumSubhead"> Information housed outside </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div ng-show="(choice | filter: {mustShow: 'yes'}).length > 0">
  <input name="first_name" class="text_box_space" type="text" value="" style="color: black;" size="25" width="200px">
</div>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ETSW76OJCdg6oVkpTAQh?p=preview)

Comment: I modified my question, actually i am talking about only radio button. Text box is not in the picture.

Comment: @user3853398 did you checked the plunkr which I;ve attached to my answer..?

Comment: Many Thanks...really saved my time

Comment: @user3853398 Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: In ur solution instead of length<div ng-show="(choice | filter: {mustShow: 'yes'}).length > 0 , how to compare it with yes value like mustShow='Yes'. Thanks

Comment: you could use `Yes` instead `yes`

Comment: I tried this way but its not working  <div ng-show="choice.mustShow=='yes'">. I want to show/hide this based on the one of the radio button selected.

Comment: you can not have access to ng-repeat variable ouside ng-repeat..you could achieve this by filter.tell me what are you requirement..??

Comment: thanks. I changed radio to checkbox in Demo Plunkr of ur solution. Then its not working. The text box is not displayed based on checkbox where as solution works with radio buttons alone. Pls can help how to make it work with checkbox

Comment: @user3853398 you could open new question for..extending this story wouldn't make any sense to me.. Thanks :)

Comment: I did so. Pls can you provide a solution